# pinecone ingest requested feature 'Namespaces' is not supported

Tags: pinecone

Im following this tutorial https://github.com/chroma-core/gpt4-pdf-chatbot-langchain-chroma

but get an error when ingesting the PDF to Pinecone

```
error [PineconeError: PineconeClient: Error calling upsert: PineconeError: The requested feature 'Namespaces' is not supported by the current index type 'Starter'.]
```

do I need to upgrade the pinecone tier?

Answer (score 4):

Namespace is not for free tier or starter, you can leave namespace empty this issue will be solved; here I;ve comment out the namespace:-

```
await PineconeStore.fromDocuments(
  pageLevelDocs,
  embeddings,
  {
    pineconeIndex,
    // namespace: createdFile.id,
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by deleting the "Starter" project that is provided when you sign up and by creating a new (free tier) project.

Comment: I did this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Pinecone no longer provides gcp-free environments (only gcp-starter). You must either upgrade your plan or discontinue using the namespace feature.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, changing

```js
await index.namespace(namespace).upsert(vectors);
```

to

```js
await index.upsert(vectors);
```

resolved the issue without changing the free tier nor the pinecone project configuration

Answer (score 0):

if your environment for the project is `gcp-starter` it does not support namespaces. You can still use the free-tier by creating a new project:

1. Delete the project because the free tier only supports 1 project. (If you get a bad response deleting the project, delete any indexes you created first).
2. Create a new project, and index.
3. The new project will have a different environment that you choose when you create the project.
4. Create a new index and get the new API Key